# Highcharts How to display total of data classes in legend

Tags: highcharts

I built a bubble map with Highmaps: [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/cwr1dqav/1/)

Now I want to display the total of the data classes in the legend and therefore added this code:

```
labelFormatter: function () {
                total = this.total;


            return (this.name) + ' (' + total + ')';
        },
```

Unfortunately I do not get a value. What do I have to change?

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, What exact value you want to display as `total`?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I want to display the ammount of values in each data class of the color axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of points that belong to a specific data class is not stored, so you need to calculate it by yourself, for example:

```
labelFormatter: function() {
  var chart = this.chart,
    from = this.from,
    to = this.to,
    data,
    total,
    index;

  if (chart.legend) {
    index = chart.legend.allItems.indexOf(this);
    data = chart.series[1].options.data;

    total = data.filter(function(el) {
      return (typeof from === 'undefined' || el.neupro >= from) &&
        (typeof to === 'undefined' || el.neupro < to)
    }).length;
  }

  return (this.name) + ' (' + total + ')';
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7ajxsu6y/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter

Comment: thank you for this solution @ppotaczek Now I added a bubble legend which only works when I remove the total numbers [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wb4Ld2cr/) Do you know why?

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, You should exclude bubble legend from the formatter function - it is also a part of a legend, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/02hqngut/